# How to make property read only in model which is generated by Entity Framework (database first)?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, properties

I have a table in a SQL database with some columns `Entdate` which is "not nullable" is one of them with type of `date`.

I have set the default binding of that column with `getdate()` function. Now in my project I am using Entity Framework (database first) with mvc 4. So I got a property called `Entdate` in my model (which is generated by Entity Framework, because I am using database first approach). I don't want to pass any value to this (`EntDate`, because in the database I have used `getdate()` function as default constraint for the `Entdate` column) property, I just need to fetch the data from `Entdate` column from SQL database. How can I do this?

If I remove the set property of the `Entdate` property in model, it generates an error, I can't pass null value to it because `Entdate` is not nullable in database. What should I do? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set its `StoreGeneratedPattern` = `Computed` and its `Setter` = `private` as in this example:

[image]

Comment: thanks Gert Arnold...but i got perfect solution for this porb